# Automatic Testing always wins?

Tags: testing, automation

I am reading this page:

http://support.smartbear.com/articles/testcomplete/manager-overview/

and several other pages, it seems like automatic testing is the winner compared with manual testing, in terms of userfulness. I wonder if that is the case? Could testing experts share their idea? Thanks.

Comment: I should point out that is a marketing page for a an automated testing tools providor, not some white paper or anything. What would you expect a salesman to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is an emphatic no, automation is not a replacement for manual testing. Automation vs. manual is not an either/or, you need both. And if I had to choose one or the other, I would choose manual testing.

With manual testing, a smart exploratory tester can cover many different test cases and permutations very quickly, see where bugs are happening, then use their smarts to find more bugs of the same ilk. Automated tests typically do the same thing every time, so they cover just one path through your software.

The way to think about it is exploratory testing is the best way to find bugs, automated tests are a way to prevent regressions. The hidden cost of automation is the long-term maintenance cost, which is far greater than the initial cost to build the automation.

I have a couple of posts on automation, here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2008/08/15/so-you-want-to-automate-your-test-cases.aspx
and here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2009/06/13/increasing-the-roi-of-our-automation.aspx

Ed.

Comment: Great points, Ed. The maintenance cost of automation (even when it's designed and implemented well) is far too often overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that is completely wrong. Automated testing will never be able to exploratory test like a rock star black boxer is able to. Also, there are no maintenance headaches with a manual tester and false positives are lot less frequent. Automation is awesome, don't get me wrong. But the reason I want automation is to take care of the simple, consistent tasks that are the basic checks to leave my black boxers free to try and break the app in ways I never would have imagined.

Answer (score 1):

yes and no. automatic testing is an important part of good software development. every developer should use it. unit tests, integration tests, function tests... use them! they will make your software better! that's for sure!

on the other side, will a human manual test make your software worse? No! So if it's appropriate, let the user test your software. what is the user experience? is your software easy to use? does it what the user expects?

both (automatic test and manual tests) will help you to improve your code. find a suitable mix for your project.

Answer (score 1):

All of the advantages given for automated testing in your link are accurate enough, though I would add "...if done properly" to each one. Poorly designed or implemented automated testing can lead to the exact opposite (I've seen all of the following!):

- **cost time and money to troubleshoot or maintain, due to poor accuracy** - for example, if the test fails frequently due to timing variations or variations in the testing environment that are not properly accounted for, or if the test depends on some undocumented behavior that later gets changed
- **reduce test coverage** - if developers rely on the automated tests too heavily and do not take the time to think about how best to exercise the specific code they're working on ("I'm fixing a bug that involves interaction between X and Y, so if I run the unit test for X and the unit test for Y, that covers everything!")
- **miss what manual testing can do** - for example, the benefit and curse of automated testing is that it does the same exact thing every time. The human factor in manual testing (variation in timing, accidental mouse-clicks or typos, changing the order in which you do things, paying attention to usability) can uncover issues that would otherwise have been missed by an automated test.
- **harm team morale** - if getting fragile automated tests to pass at all costs takes focus away from actually ensuring that the system is working as intended.

That said, sensibly designed and implemented automated tests are absolutely a benefit. I would argue though that a sane mixture of automated and manual testing is generally better than "all automation, all the time". Some particularly complex one-off tests may not justify the additional time and cost involved in automating them to re-run later. And unless your automation is ludicrously comprehensive, the variation inherent in manual testing always provides some additional confidence and the possibility of uncovering things that the automated test procedure may not have encountered.